# How to detect birds appearance in the nest?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-processing

I am very new to video processing, but friend of mine - biologist came up with an interesting problem.

**Task**

There is a camera pointing to a particular bird nest. The footage is large (hundreds of hours). The task is to give specified time ranges, when a bird visited the nest.

**Some problems**
*task specific*

- The image is shaking - due to the wind, so the background is not stationary.
- The overall quality is not high 640x480 and there isn't great contrast.
- The bird blends with the background.

*me specific*

- My C++ experience lives in the future not in the past.
- OpenCV ..well, let's only making it work was like a day of work. Ok, that was due to the fact, that I was trying to make it work for Python3.5. Didn't work. Then it did. But it didn't open a file. Anyway, that's the reason why I've switched to C++ (not to mention code running x-times faster).
- Close to zero experience with VisualProcessing.

You can see the project [`here`](https://github.com/quapka/kuku) on github. There is an example footage (test_kuku.avi) of the input video and the outcome of `/src/main.cpp` script (bw_test_kuku.mp4).

**What I've done so far?**

I've converted the file to grayscale and then applied black/white threshold. After playing a little bit I've arrived at 120 (from 0-255) as it seems to remove most of the noise and the bird is still visible.

**Thoughts**

- Use some kind of threshold for the number `b_ratio = black_pixs / (black_pixs + white_pixs)` pixels. This would be nice, if it would work, however just watching the output video I can tell, that there are frames with higher `b_ratio` without the bird than with it. But This idea might be used partially - e.g. selecting only the parts of the video with higher `b_ratio` for further analysis.
- Changing the color of the pixels based on the color of it's neigbhours. This might help to remove the noise even further (you can see a lot of little color pieces in vids/bw_test_kuku.mp4)..

  ```
  255 | 255 | 255         255 | 255 | 255  
  ----|-----|----         ----|-----|----
  255 |  0  |  0   ====>  255 | 255 |  0 
  ----|-----|----         ----|-----|----
   0  | 255 | 255          0  | 255 | 255
  ```
- The last idea is to calculate some kind vector how specifi pixels *move*. You can see a lot of back and forth motion (from the wind). So, this should be omitted, but when the bird arrives it creates a sort of *flow* in one direction. So that should be noted.

**Question**

I am hoping this answer won't be closed for _too broad__ etc. If so, please, point me in some direction. My general question is how to tackle similar problem. And maybe concrete pieces of code/algorithm etc. Thanks!

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks, now I feel really up for this task!

Comment: Seriously though, there are entire books written on this topic, and this is not an easy problem to solve. Far too broad for StackOverflow.  :)

Comment: I understand that, any ideas, where to start then? I hope it does not sound like I am asking stackoverflow guys to solve it for me. Maybe I should have stated it more like: "Algorithm for recognizing moving objects." Although I would not expect better response :) Thanks for the laughs though.

Comment: I would guess: 1) process the video to get a stabilized video; I'm not sure the state of the art here, but I imagine with a non-static background this gets hard. 2) Identify the location you want to detect movement in (maybe easy if you get a well-stabilized video?) 3) Detect movement. This is probably very hard if you don't want false positives. 4) Detect if it's a bird; research-level. For example, here's Google's paper on detecting faces, https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832, and this took a ton of joint effort and lots of resources. Also, given the amount of data, make sure it's parallelized.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've probably wrote something different from what I want. I think detecting moving object - with the risk of false positives is great result on its own. I see now. No, I don't expect the algorithm to distinguish between say bird and a leaf. Let's say _detect something entering/leaving the shot_ would be great. And thanks for the steps and link.

Comment: _"detect something entering/leaving the shot"_  just google for "motion detection algorithms". Normally "background subtraction" or even "frame differencing" would be used but might be tricky here since "bird blends with background" and "footage is shaky". Just some topics to research while you wait for better advice.

Comment: To me this sounds like a classification problem: bird/no bird. I guess machine learning / deep learning would be very useful here. I remember watching a webinar from mathworks about detecting if a video shows a cat or a dog. The steps described in the webinar could be useful for you. I haven't found (neither searched long) for the video, but maybe you can find it. A quick google search gave me this: https://youtu.be/r4D3NxQ0Xhg (could be similar, but I haven't watched it).

Comment: what about video stabilization as a first step?

Answer (score -1):

As you are looking for something short and sweet, try any of these:

1. Apply gaussian filters
2. Energy calculation - sobel et al.
3. Pretrained Caffe framework - Deep Learning framework

   This option will really give you results, but you may need to do some pre-processing.
4. Train a Deep Learning framework with your data